# Find the maximum element in an array which has the minimum position

Tags: c++, vector, max, minimum

How can I find the maximum value in a vector which has the minimum position?

For example, if I have the vector `v[5] = {2,2,1,1,1}` the output will be `v[0]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What have you tried? Generally, people will help you fix your code if you show what you've tried, but won't write your code for you.  Clearly, there is a 2-pass algorithm where the first pass through the array determines the maximum value and the second pass determines which index that value occurs at first. However, there's also a 1-pass algorithm. You should look for that. It really isn't all that hard. Also, you're interested in the index which represents the minimum position at which the maximum value appears, not the value.

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic way to do it would be to use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). This returns an iterator to the largest element:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::max_element
#include <iterator>  // for std::begin, std::end
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  v[5] = {2,2,1,1,1};
  auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
  std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

If you need the index of the element, you can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
 std::cout << "index " << std::distance(std::begin(v), it) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the maximum value in the array from the end of the array for a single pass implementation

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in your own loop:

```
if(!v.size()) return -1;
int maxValue = v[0], maxPosition = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
    if(v[i] > maxValue) maxValue = v[maxPosition = i];
}
return maxPosition;
```

If you want to get the last occurence of the maximum, just change `if(v[i] > maxValue)` to `if(v[i] >= maxValue)` or change the loop to work back to front.